# Additional packagesToScan alongside with classes in persistence.xml

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

We have an old enterprise system, with different persistence units defined in persistece.xml's, a lot of services using entityManager annotated with @PersistenceContext(unitName = "some_of_those_unit_names") etc.

Now we are substracting smaller backends from it, using Spring Boot. So, for a long time jpa config looked like:

```
    @Bean
    fun entityManagerFactory(): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        return LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean().also {
            it.dataSource = someDataSource
            it.persistenceUnitName = "some_of_those_unit_names"
            it.jpaVendorAdapter = HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()
            it.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties())
        }
    }
```

and on application start up there was a line in the log:
"Found explicit default unit with name (some_of_those_unit_names) in some_persistence.xml - overriding local default unit settings"

So spring used the same persistence.xml's as an old system and they worked nice alongside. We reused the same services as an old system, just importing them as @Beans in spring configuration.

Now my problem is. I need to add entities, that would be managed ONLY for particular spring backend, but not from an old system or other spring backends using the same persistence unit name.

So:

- I can not add them to persistence.xml used by an old system and other backends
- I can not skip setting persistenceUnitName while creating entityManagerFactory or use another persistence unit name - as this particular name is used in imported services in @PersistenceContext annotation
- If I use setPackagesToScan AND persistenceUnitName - then spring just uses corresponding persistence.xml and ignores "setPackagesToScan".

What can I do here to completely override persistence.xml or just extend its set of managed classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end instead of using setPackagesToScan I used setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors.
And created my custom post processor, adding managed classes in it:

```
class SuperCustomPersistenceUnitPostProcessor : PersistenceUnitPostProcessor {
    override fun postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(pui: MutablePersistenceUnitInfo) {
        pui.addManagedClassName(SomeNewEntity::class.qualifiedName)
        pui.addManagedClassName(AnotherEntity::class.qualifiedName)
    }
}
```